Wolfram|Alpha notebook cannot parse correct code
I'm using Wolfram|Alpha notebook on Wolfram cloud, but it fails to parse my code:

Here's the Wolfram|Alpha notebook:
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/7d26639b-0545-4969-896f-b54c99cf00ba
Is it a bug that is leading to "No Wolfram Language Translation Found" message despite apparently the code entered correctly?
Mathematica being a mathematical software at its core, is it then not safe to implement in a production site of mission critical importance.
While using Python on an IDE (like Visual Studio), I never encounter a situation when the code is correct and output incorrect.

I do not use Cloud myself, it looks like natural language input (this is when you hit = at start of cell and get the RED equal sign prompt)  for the cloud did not understand the input. I tried same thing in Mathematica V 14.1 itself and did not get this error.  https://i.sstatic.net/ZL6LjMOm.png


Are you using Wolfram|Alpha Notebook? If so, please explicitly mention this in the question. 2. I can't reproduce the issue: https://i.sstatic.net/pBerPeQf.png 3. Please don't add [tag:bugs] tag until the community or WRI has confirmed it.


https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/7d26639b-0545-4969-896f-b54c99cf00ba  (I need to figure out if it is Wolfram Notebook or Wolfram Alpha Notebook).

Indeed, it's a Wolfram|Alpha Notebook. Seems that those blank lines after the code is causing problem. After deleting it, the code is parsing correctly. Not sure if this should be called a bug or a limitation of Wolfram|Alpha Notebook. (Personally I'd suggest not using Wolfram|Alpha Notebook. )

Extend my comment to an answer. It's an issue of Wolfram|Alpha notebook edition, and it's not limited to Wolfram cloud:

Steps to reproduce the issue:

Create a Wolfram|Alpha notebook.

Create at least 2 more blank lines by pressing Shift+Enter before entering the code.

Input Style["A","Title"] and execute.


So it's easy to fix: just remove the redundant blank lines.
I'm not sure if this should be considered as a bug or a limitation of Wolfram|Alpha notebook, but personally I'd suggest not using Wolfram|Alpha notebook because free-form input is not stable. There's no need to use free-form input as long as you're writing syntactically correct code.
